# New operating column under several conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is an simple exemple of my problem:

```
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':10}, {'a':1, 'b': 3, 'c': 10}, {'a':2, 'b': 1, 'c': 20}, {'a':3, 'b': 4, 'c': 30}] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

    a     b     c
0   1     2     10
1   1     3     10
2   2     1     20
3   3     4     30
```

Now, I would like to create a new column 'd' which subtracts 'c' if a[i] == a[j] and b[i] != b[j]

My expected result is :

```
    a     b     c     d
0   1     2     10    0
1   1     3     10    0
2   2     1     20   
3   3     4     30
```

I have already made a loop but it takes me too long with more than 17000 lines to make and being new to python I wonder if there's not a faster way?

Comment: What do you mean by subtract c? Shouldn't there be just one entry in `d` because you can only perform one subtract operation on 2 numbers of `c`? What if there are 3 `a` that are the same?

Comment: what is the relation between i and j? is j = i+1 or something?

Comment: @RockyLi There can only be two  `a` plus in `d` I expected to subtract the other `c` corresponding.
@Jacobr365 I meant it wasn't the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have expanded your examples:

```
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':10}, {'a':1, 'b': 3, 'c': 10}, {'a':1, 'b':3, 'c':20}, {'a':1, 'b':4, 'c':30},
        {'a':2, 'b': 1, 'c': 20}, {'a':3, 'b': 4, 'c': 30},
        {'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c':100}] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# raw data:
   a  b    c
0  1  2   10
1  1  3   10
2  1  3   20
3  1  4   30
4  2  1   20
5  3  4   30
6  3  5  100
```

Add column `d`:

```
df["d"] = df["c"].diff()[(df["a"].diff().eq(0)) & (df["b"].diff().ne(0))]
```

Result:

```
   a  b    c     d
0  1  2   10   NaN
1  1  3   10   0.0
2  1  3   20   NaN
3  1  4   30  10.0
4  2  1   20   NaN
5  3  4   30   NaN
6  3  5  100  70.0
```

Note how index 2 doesn't have a value because `b[i] == b[i-1]`

**EDIT:**

Added the extra constraints per comment:

```
# remove cases promised to not be there.
data = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':10}, {'a':1, 'b': 3, 'c': 10},
    {'a':2, 'b': 1, 'c': 20}, {'a':3, 'b': 4, 'c': 30},
    {'a': 3, 'b': 5, 'c':100}] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# raw data:
   a  b    c
0  1  2   10
1  1  3   10
4  2  1   20
5  3  4   30
6  3  5  100

# Get `d`
df["d"] = df["c"].diff()[(df["a"].diff().eq(0)) & (df["b"].diff().ne(0))]
df["d"] = df["d"].combine_first(df["d"].shift(-1))

# result:
   a  b    c     d
0  1  2   10   0.0
1  1  3   10   0.0
2  2  1   20   NaN
3  3  4   30  70.0
4  3  5  100  70.0
```

Comment: Your example works perfectly but when I want to transpose it I only get `NaN`

Comment: Also @RockyLi there can only be 2 `a` and for exemple for index 0 `d` should be `20 - 10 = 10` and index 1 `d` is well `10 - 10 = 0`

Comment: Edited per your setting. Can you clarify your problem with transpose?

Comment: @RockiLi I mean when I apply it to my data it gives me `NaN`. Maybe it's because the data from `a` is mixed up ? In your exemple I expected from index 3 to be `30 - 100  = - 70`

Comment: Yes, preferably you should do `df = df.sort_values(by="a")` before applying this.

Comment: @RockiLi Yes work perfectly with `df = df.sort_values(by="a")`. Also for the problem of index 3 I just multiplied by -1. Thank you very much !